# How to prevent user input?

Tags: java, android

My `activity_main.xml`'s interface is **shared** by `MainActivity.java` (which contains the actual code for buttons), and `SecondActivity.java`.

The problem is , It would let the user play around with the buttons, when they are in `MainActivity`, but If they are in `SecondActivity`, and they were to press a button, It would crash my app, because It doesn't have the code for the buttons.

So how do I prevent user clicking the screen in `SecondActivity`?

Comment: If those elements shouldn't exist in second activity, either use another layout, or make the elements disappear

Comment: Sounds like one activity should be enough

Answer (score 3):

To disable button presses and preventing an `OnClick` event to fire you can use the following code on your respective buttons

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id)).setEnabled(false);
```

The code simply disables the button, to activate it again, you can use the same syntax, but replace the `boolean` parameter with `true`

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id)).setEnabled(true);
```